# `lsp` does not start on python-mode-hook

Tags: python, hooks, lsp

I am using `lsp` under Python.`lsp` does not start when a Python file is opened, I have to do `M-x lsp` for each file I open. Also when I switch from `find-file` to another file I have to do `M-x lsp` all over again.

I have followed: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
```

What may be the reason for this? Is there any way to force `lsp` to start on all Python file whenever I open them?

---

I observe that when I start running `emacs` in the `ibuffer` there is python files that are located under the parent folder where those won't run LSP when I open them. But when I open another file in sub-folder it loads `LSP` by defualt.

example

- `emacs -nw ~/home.py` and do `M-x find-file` `~/repo/work.py` => `lsp` than `M-x find-file` `~/repo/work1.py` ; `lsp` is enabled automatically right away.
- But if I do `emacs -nw ~/repo/work.py` ; than `M-x find-file` `~/repo/work1.py` ; `lsp` is not enabled by default for both.

---

I have following files all has `import os` in it. I am coming on top of `os` and do `xref-find-definitions`.

```
~/file1.py

.repo
├── file1.py
├── file2.py
└── file3.py
```

I do `emacs -nw ~/file1.py` and `find-file` `repo/file1.py` and LSP works. But afterwards when I do `find-file` to `repo/file2.py` now it does not :-(

Comment: Does LSP not prompt you to import the project when you invoke lsp on a single file? LSP should start automatically for all files once you import the project in to the workspace.

Comment: You can also invoke `lsp-workspace-folders-add` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Can it add the base folder by default when emacs starts? I have tried `lsp-workspace-folders-add` but still when I open another file using `find-file` I have to run `lsp` to enable it again.

Comment: Seems like when I open `emacs` python folders in the base folder already open within and they won't load `LSP` by default

Comment: Like I do `emacs -nw ~/hello.py` than `find-file`  to ~/repo/work.py it works. But if I do `emacs -nw ~/repo/work.py` it does not work

Comment: Could try moving `~/hello.py` and others into another subdirectory under `$HOME` and then try? If I import a lsp project, then `A/B/*.py`, `A/*.py`, and `A/C/*.cpp` (say) all work automatically.

Comment: Please see my updated question where what I tried

Comment: Please see my updated question where what I tried. I feel like some settings in my init.el like elpy or jedi may cause this.

Comment: I am not not sure what could the exact reason be. Sharing an MWE might help. Otherwise, you could try filing a bug on the LSP page at GitHub.

Comment: @alper, if you really want to use lsp, then wipe out everything related to elpy and jedi (jedi.el I mean; jedi python module should be in your python installation). python-language-server uses jedi python module.

Comment: In order to wipe out can I do `M-x package-delete ` and `elpy* jedi*` ? In my `.emacs` file there is some functions related to `elpy  and jedi` I will also remove them

Comment: @Ian I was using jedi for auto-complete suggestions, can lsp provide the same functionality?

Comment: Ref: elpy* - I don't know. Ref autocompletion, just copy-paste the ```(use-package company...)``` from ```emacs-rust-config``` folder, hope you still have it. It is a very good configuration and works with lsp.

Comment: @Ian Thanks well after few days of work and some luck I think I was able to make it work. `emacs-rust-config` is golden rope, I have tried to merge it with my own configuration (where I just appended added my init.el file on top of it and remove `elpy` `jedi` like you suggessted). // https://github.com/avatar-lavventura/dotfiles/blob/main/init_alper.el